How to indicate which project initiate the setup (project) process in Playwright
In my playwright.config file I have multiple projects that all has the same setup project as a dependency project.
Is there any way to indicate on runtime, which parent project initiate the setup process?
playwright.config
projects: [
    { name: "setup", testMatch: /.*\.setup\.ts/ },
    {
      name: "foo",
      dependencies: ["setup"],
    },
    {
      name: "bar",
      dependencies: ["setup"],
    },
]

setup test
setup("setup test", async ({ page }, testInfo) => {
  console.log(testInfo.project.name); // output: "setup"

  /* What I'm looking for: */
  // console.log(testInfo.paretProject.name);

  /* Or */
  // console.log(testInfo.project.parentName)
});

(Or maybe something like providing the initiator name within the project dependency properties somehow)

You could do this to get all parent projects: filter out projects that has current project as dependency.
Note: This will not filter out projects that are not being run, e.g. if running npx playwright test --project "foo", both parent projects will still be returned.
import { test as setup } from "@playwright/test";

setup("Setup", async ({}, testInfo) => {
  const parentProjects = testInfo.config.projects
    .filter((project) => project.dependencies.includes(testInfo.project.name))
    .map((project) => project.name);

  // returns: ['foo', 'bar']
  console.log(parentProjects);
});



Ok, that's exactly what I'm asking -how to indicate which one of those cause the current setup execution
